# Fit single string to a template

Tags: python, string, format

I want to fit a string to a template like this

```
s = '12345678901234'
print('{0}.{1}.{2}/{3}-{4}'.format(s[0:2], s[2:5], s[5:8], s[8:12], s[12:]))

12.345.678/9012-34
```

Or using formatted string literals:

```
print(f'{s[0:2]}.{s[2:5]}.{s[5:8]}/{s[8:12]}-{s[12:]}')
```

Is there some formatting string syntax to fit the string without slicing it first?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand how magical you want the fit to be. Somehow you need to tell it that you want a fit like `12.345.678/9012-34` rather than `123.45.678/9012-34` or any other or the many varieties. It seems like the slice is a pretty simple way to do that.

Comment: Sorry; it's unclear to me what you mean by "magically". You mean you want to take those specific slices without specifying them?

Comment: @Mark I was hoping for some format string syntax, say ```';2.;3.;3/;4-;2'.format(s)```

Comment: Are you doing this once (i.e. one line in one code location), or multiple times?

Comment: @Vercingatorix This script does it only twice, with different formats. But it happens frequently. I guess I will just create a module with functions

Answer (score 1):

Not very magical, but less typing I guess?

```
s = '12345678901234'
x = 0

splits = [s[x:(x:=x+i)] for i in [2, 3, 3, 4, 2]]
print('{}.{}.{}/{}-{}'.format(*splits))
```

Comment: Nice. I can imagine it as a function ```my_format(the_string, the_split_lengths, the_delimiters)```

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = '12345678901234'
i = -1
print(''.join([c if c != 'X' else s[i:=i+1] for c in "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX"]))
```

The following is more Pythonic, but is longer:

```py
from itertools import count

s = '12345678901234'
i = count(0)
print(''.join([c if c != 'X' else s[next(i)] for c in "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX"]))
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to turn this string into a class and use `__str__`:

```py
class Serialnum:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def __str__(self):
        i = count(0)
        return ''.join([c if c != 'X' else self.s[next(i)] for c in "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX"])

myserialnum = Serialnum('12345678901234')
print(myserialnum)
```